# Easier way to write multiple "not equal" attribute selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I currently have a selector that looks like this:

```
$("span[row!='2'][row!='5'][row!='1']");
```

Is there an easier way to write this? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
$("span[row!='1,2,5']");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no way to combine not equal selectors in this manner.  The result would be interpretted as the string `'1,2,3'` and not individual values.  You'll have to enumerate the cases.

You could though write a function to make this easier to write.  For example

```
var makeNotEquals = function(name) {
  var clause = '';
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    clause = clause + '[' + name + '!=\'' + arguments[i] + '\']';
  }
  return clause;
}
```

Usage

```
var selector = 'span' + makeNotEquals('row', 2, 1, 5);
$(selector)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have to do this a lot and there isn't a better way to solve this problem by attaching appropriate classes to the like groups of rows, then you could write a short jQuery plugin that you could pass an array of row numbers to like this:

```
$("span[row]").filterAttribute("row", ['1','2','5'], true)
```

And this is an implementation of that:

```
$.fn.filterAttribute = function(attr, values, reverse) {
    var remaining = [];
    this.each(function(index, el) {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (el.getAttribute(attr) == values[i]) {
                remaining.push(el);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    if (reverse) {
        return(this.not(remaining));
    } else {
        return($(remaining));
    }
}
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/WwrSY/

Note, the normal operation of this plugin is to filter items from the jQuery object so that items that do not match are removed, returning a new jQuery object with the specified items as the only ones kept (like jQuery's `.filter()` works.  The third parameter can reverse the filter so that the items specified will be the ones removed, not kept which is what the OP has asked for with their != syntax.

Due to the wonders of automatic type conversion, this can also be used like this with the values passed as numbers:

```
$(".aaa").filterAttribute("row", [1, 2, 3], true)
```